# How do I show that is G has no right options, then there exists an n $\in$ $\Bbb Z$, where $G = n$

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I know that if $A+B+C=0 \to a+b+c=0$, and by extrapolating I can get $A+B=C \to a+b=c$, and I know that it will have to be an inductive proof, but I'm not sure how to phrase the proof. I'm assuming that the base case will be the $0+1=1$, but I'm not sure where I would go from there. I know that the whole proof will be true, as (for example) if you add another Left option to a Red-Green-Blue Hackenbush Game, where there are no Right Options, the value of the Game will increase by one. I know that the Inductive Step will be showing that $n + (1) = n+1$, so would my Inductive Hypothesis be:

For all games G, where there are no Right Options, there exists a $k \lt n$, and  $k, n \in \Bbb Z$, where if $G = k$, and $H = 1$, then $G + 1 = k+1$.

Any help or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, and sorry if the formatting isn't perfect.

Comment: Are you assuming only that $G$ itself has no right options, or are you also assuming that the (left) options of $G$, and their options, etc., all have no right options?

Comment: @AndreasBlass There are no right options in G. Left will win after the next move, and we're trying to determine the value of the two games being added, both with no Right Options.

Comment: I wouldn't look at sums, per se. If you're trying to prove that games with no right options in subpositions are equal to nonnegative integers, then the way to do it by induction is to take such a game, and assume as an inductive hypothesis that all of its options are equal to integers. Then you should be able to prove that the original game is equal to a certain integer as well.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @MarkS. I was! I used Red-Green-Blue Hackenbush to solve it, and showed since every blue "tree" n-segments long was equal to the integer n, then adding one more blue segment to the tree would equal n+1. With that, you could show that a tree equivalent to every integer is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! Something along those lines works for the case of games whose subpositions have no right options. But if your goal is really to show this for any game with no right options, then unfortunately, not every game with no right options is an all-blue Hackenbush tree. For instance, what if $G$ is the game "Right has no move, but Left has one move to a single green Hackenbush edge".